# Statistics of Variable Range Using Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to calculate min, max, average using data criteria. The image below shows two columns of data namely time and speed. I want to calculate the average speed for the range from time 0 (cell 2) to cell 14. Then, calculate the average speed from the next 0 (cell 15) to cell 20, and so forth. Obviously, the same formula can be applied to calculate min, max, and other statistics.

Is there a way to write a smart formula that knows how to average each segment separately? The image below illustrates three segments, but my original dataset is much bigger: [image]

Comment: Added an alternative approach to @virtualdvid with a reduced number of helper cells (only in summary) demonstrating the use of the `Indirect` function. Maybe it's of help to other users, too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a column to group when it finds a `0`.

1. Initialize the cell with `1` and in the next cell use `=IF(A3=0,C2+1,C2)`
2. Then you can use the formulas, `AVERAGEIF`, `MINIFS`, `MAXIFS`. (Available only in Excel v2016).

   ```
   =AVERAGEIF($C$2:$C$17,E2,$B$2:$B$17)
   =MINIFS($B$2:$B$17,$C$2:$C$17,E2)
   =MAXIFS($B$2:$B$17,$C$2:$C$17,E2)
   ```

[image]

Comment: Same principle applied with pivottable I am guessing where they can use val in the row or column as well as summarized within the data area? Also, MINIFs.. are only available in later versions of 2016. :-(

Comment: I appreciate your help in this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Approach with helper column only in summary**

You don't need to fill *all data rows* with a helper column, you can **confine input to the summary range**.
This approach uses the `Indirect` function in the summary range to `Match` each last cell in a data block (identified by 0) and
calculate results via the `Subtotal` function (arguments *1-average, 5-minimum, 4-maximum*).

1. Initialize cell **E1** with **`=1`**
2. Then you can write the following formul*ae* into row **E2:H2** and copy them down as long as you find data blocks. Column **E** shows the last cells in each block, **F:H** display averages, minima and maxima:

   **E2**    `=MATCH(0,INDIRECT("$A" &$E1+2 & ":$A$10000"),0)+$E1`

   **F2**    `=SUBTOTAL(1,INDIRECT("$B$" & $E1 +1 & ":$B$" & $E2))`
   **G2**    `=SUBTOTAL(5,INDIRECT("$B$" & $E1 +1 & ":$B$" & $E2))`
   **H2**    `=SUBTOTAL(4,INDIRECT("$B$" & $E1 +1 & ":$B$" & $E2))`

**Note**

a) It's necessary to have a closing zero (`0`) in the last data row.

b) This example assumes the helper items in column $E; you can easily change that to any column.